# Get array of Map's keys

Tags: java, python, arrays, dictionary

I am trying to learn Java with a Python basis, so please bear with me.

I am implementing a Sieve of Eratosthenes method (I have one in Python; trying to convert it to Java):

```
def prevPrimes(n):
    """Generates a list of primes up to 'n'"""
    primes_dict = {i : True for i in range(3, n + 1, 2)}
    for i in primes_dict:
        if primes_dict[i]:
            num = i
        while (num * i <= n):
            primes_dict[num*i] = False
            num += 2
    primes_dict[2] = True
    return [num for num in primes_dict if primes_dict[num]]
```

This is my attempt to convert it to Java:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Sieve {
    public static void sieve(int n){
        System.out.println(n);
        Map primes = new HashMap();
        for(int x = 0; x < n+1; x++){
            primes.put(x, true);
        }
        Set primeKeys = primes.keySet();
        int[] keys = toArray(primeKeys);  // attempt to convert the set to an array
        System.out.println(primesKeys); // the conversion does not work
        for(int x: keys){
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        // still have more to add
        System.out.println(primes);
    }
}
```

The error I get is that it cannot find the method `toArray(java.util.Set)`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

First of all, use generics:

```
Map<Integer, Boolean> map = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
Set<Integer> keys = map.keySet();
```

Second, to convert the set to an array, you can use `toArray(T[] a)`:

```
Integer[] array = keys.toArray(new Integer[keys.size()]);
```

and if you want `int` instead of `Integer`, then iterate over each element:

```
int[] array = new int[keys.size()];
int index = 0;
for(Integer element : keys) array[index++] = element.intValue();
```

Comment: saved my life , I would recommend just 
`for(Integer element : keys) array[index++] = element.intValue();`
to be replaced with 
`for(Integer element : keys) array[index++] = element`
to remove boxing

Answer (score 3):

Use `primeKeys.toArray()` instead of `toArray(primeKeys)`.

Comment: `int[] keys = primeKeys.toArray()` highlights the parentheses and I get this error: `incompatible types`.

Answer (score 2):

`toArray()` is a member of the `Collection` class, so just put `Collection.toArray(...)` and import java.util.Collection;

Note: `toArray()` returns an `Object[]`, so you'll have to cast it to Integer[] and assign it to an Integer[] reference:

```
Integer[] array = (Integer[])Collection.toArray( someCollection );
```

Thanks to autoboxing, Integers now work like ints, most of the time.

edit:  dan04's solution is pretty cool, wish I'd thought of that...anyway, you'll still have to cast and assign to a Object[] type.